# Simple curve smoothing in matplotlib --- equivalent to gnuplot's "smooth bezier"?

Tags: python, matplotlib, smoothing

I have a set of points I want to plot in matplotlib, say:

```
x = [1,4,6,7,8]
y = [0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6]
```

In gnuplot, I used to be able to directly use the 'plot' command's smooth property to get a smooth curve on a graph, without having to preprocess the data.

Is there an equivalent in matplotlib---specify a set of points, and tell it how to smooth it, bezier or spline or something like that?

If not, what is the easiest way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [scipy's interpolation and curve-fitting functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) are the closest you are going to get.  I don't know of anything built into matplotlib.